# $injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseArrayProvider <- $firebaseArray <-

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn ionic+firebase. Came across a [tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-04-ionic-screencast.html) to create grocery list. It works fine with ionic but when I try to use firebase, it fails with error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseArrayProvider <- $firebaseArray <- Items
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseArrayProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseArray%20%3C-%20Items

Also checked the above link that comes with the error. But I still couldn't clearly understand the reason.

Here's my code:

[index.html](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c8026cbd72e71a83b274)
[app.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b961cc86ffc3cec6dee)

Any help is very much appreciated.

[UPDATE] : I have now added firebase.js file locally inside my js folder and referencing it from there. The error persists.

Comment: what is telling you is that you are trying to use a  $firebaseArray service but there is no code connected to it (no Provider). that usally means wither you forgot to list the firebase module as your  dependency on your applications declaration and maybe forgot to include the script tag in the index.html. BTW cant access your code

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon Here are the links: 
index.html -> http://pastebin.com/zEGSN4sA
app.js -> http://pastebin.com/FANjdL9v

Comment: sorry i cant reach that, my proxy won't allow it

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I have added that dependency in app.js

angular.module('starter', ['ionic','firebase'])
 .factory('Items', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray){
         var itemsRef = new Firebase('https://grocerylistdemo.firebaseio.com/items');
         return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
     }])

Also, in index.html,
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <!-- Firebase -->
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>


      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.js"></script>

Comment: and still getting the same error?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon yes, still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your version of angularfire as the version you have doesn't support **$firebaseArray** and $firebaseObject. However, if you want to keep your current version, then use **$asArray()** and $asObject() instead.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject firebase to your app module

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services','firebase'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When taking a look at the angularfire.js file, we can notice that the name of the firebaseArray starts with a capital F ($FirebaseArray). When we use $firebaseArray with small f as shown on the documentation, we get the unknow provider error.

This is the factory declaration:  (version AngularFire 0.9.2)

```
angular.module('firebase').factory('$FirebaseArray', ["$log", "$firebaseUtils"
```

On later releases, this was corrected.

hope it helps.